# Why is this Python code raising an error?

Tags: python, windows-10

When Im typing for example NICK and HASLO I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:/Wszystko/WONSZ/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    nick = nick()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

When I type nick and haslo it works but either not
So what I should do to fix it?
Here is the code:

```
x = int
y = int

def nick():
    print ("Podaj swoj nick: ",end=' ')
    nick = input()
    return nick

def haslo():
    print ("Podaj swoje haslo: ",end=' ')
    haslo = input()
    return haslo

print ("Witaj!!!")

while True:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    nick = nick()
    haslo = haslo()

    if nick == "nick":
        x += 1

    if haslo == "haslo":
        y += 1

    if x==0:
        print("Nick bledny")
        if y == 0:
            print("Haslo bledne")
    if x==1 and y==1:
         break

print("Zalogowano")
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: why are you using same names for the variable and the function and the user input `nick = nick()` and `nick = input()`?

Comment: At the end of one loop, `nick` is a string and you do `nick()` in the next iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeating variable and function names can be dangerous. In your case, the code got messy, and Python can't properly tell if you are referring to a variable or a function.

Here, I changed the name of the variables. Not only it works, it's also easier to read:

```
x = int
y = int

def nick():
    print ("Podaj swoj nick: ",end=' ')
    nickInput = input()
    return nickInput

def haslo():
    print ("Podaj swoje haslo: ",end=' ')
    hasloInput = input()
    return hasloInput

print ("Witaj!!!")

while True:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    nickVar = nick()
    hasloVar = haslo()

    if nickVar == "nick":
        x += 1

    if hasloVar == "haslo":
        y += 1

    if x==0:
        print("Nick bledny")
        if y == 0:
            print("Haslo bledne")
    if x==1 and y==1:
         break

print("Zalogowano")
```

Comment: Oh I understand. I will remember that... Next time

Comment: No problem. Just don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue :)